# Checking the String whether it is the Number(Double) of

Tags: swift, swift2

Question. It is necessary to make check the String whether it is the Number(Double)? 
Exemple:

```
var s1:String = "df1231"
var s2:String = "1231,3123"
If s1.isDouble {
  Println("True.This Number!")
} else {
  Println("False.This not Number!") //Will give it
}
If s2.isDouble {
  Println("True.This Number!") //Will give it
} else {
  Println("False.This not Number!")
}
```

Comment: what is the question?
Explain please what do you want to achieve..

Comment: If you just want to see if the string is a valid number you could just iterate over each element and see if it is a digit using the ASCII value. However the question is unclear. Please explain what you need the program to do.

Comment: Why would that be necessary? Under what circumstances? To achieve what? And Ahmed why should he use ASCII value iteration?-,-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your needs are exactly, but the most straightforward way to do it could be:

```
func isDouble(text:String) -> Bool {
    guard let _ = Double(text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: ".")) else { return false }
    return true
}

isDouble("df1231") // returns false
isDouble("1231,3123") // returns true
```

You can copy paste it to Playground to see it work.

Comment: Not very good because it ignores localization. The separator could be different from "," for example.

Comment: it's simple enough if there are no more requirements though, but don't know what the requirements are. this solution works for both commas and dots. won't work if there is both commas and dots together. but now, the questions is whether the input is always of a certain number format or varies depending on the device that's used. that i don't know.